# AWS lambda: prevent form invocation by S3:TestEvent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a Lamba triggered by PUT or POST. I made a change of an event notification setting on a bucket and then `S3:TestEvent` was invoked as it is described in the AWS document. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html

> When you configure an event notification on a bucket, Amazon S3 sends the following test message.

Is there any way to prevent it? I want to avoid unintentional Lambda executions.

Comment: Its only one time check if your permissions are ok.

Comment: As @Marcin said it is only published once (when you create notification configuration) to test if S3 can publish the event to the destination. If you are consuming events directly from a Lambda function (not via a queue) and you are not dynamically creating new S3 buckets you shouldn't worry about that.  If you really want to make sure that your function is not executed you can have a guard, which checks the event type and terminates your function accordingly. You cannot prevent function triggering on`s3:TestEvent`.